# Not able to retrieve rows from DB using where condition of type number

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, oracle11g

I have DB table Employee and it contains following fields.

**eid(VARCHAR 20) numOfUnit(Number 15,2) paidAmt(Number 15,4) paidUnit(Number 15,6)**

*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-

```
AB1001                  0                        0                           0
```

And i am trying to execute the below code in java. But it is not returning anything.

```
List <Employee> emplist = new ArrayList<Employee>(session.createQuery(
                     "from Employee where "                         
                    + " eid='AB1001' and numOfUnit='0' and paidAmt='0' and paidUnit='0'").list());
                System.out.println("emp size:: "+emplist.size());
```

Pojo Class Field definition:

```
private String eid;
              private Double numOfUnit;
              private Double paidAmt;
              private Double paidUnit;
```

I dont know what's wrong with my above query. Do we need to give decimal values(0.0) in my where condition..?

Comment: can you try two things? first is with alias and second without the decimal columns in the where condition, that way you'll know if `0` is causing the problem then try with `0.0`

Comment: In the POJO, you have an attribute called `numOfUnits` but in the query you use `numOfUnit`; is this the same in your actual code?

Comment: @MickMnemonic: Its not in the code. i corrected the typo in my question above.

Comment: How is your `Employee` entity mapped to the corresponding DB table? Note that `session.createQuery()` takes an HQL (not an SQL) query string, so the columns there should match the entity and not (necessarily) the table.

Answer (score 1):

This is speculative, but it doesn't look right to me to be comparing the `numOfUnit`, `paidAmt`, and `paidUnit` fields to string literals, when in fact those columns are numeric.  Try comparing them against numbers:

```
List <Employee> emplist = new ArrayList<Employee>(session.createQuery(
                 "from Employee where "                         
                + "eid = 'AB1001' and numOfUnit = 0 and paidAmt = 0 and paidUnit = 0").list());
System.out.println("emp size:: "+emplist.size());
```

If the above runs, but still generates an empty list, then the next thing to check is to run the corresponding raw query directly against Oracle.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. I tried the same using native query as well from my java program but still no value is retrieved. But when I try the same query in SQL developer, the data is retrieved.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE eid = 'AB1001' and numOfUnit = 0 and paidAmt = 0 and paidUnit = 0` really returns data in Oracle?

Comment: Yes. The below query returns data when executed directly in SQL developer but returns no entries in java.

SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE eid = 'AB1001' and numOfUnit = 0 and paidAmt = 0 and paidUnit = 0